# How does one integrate Newton's Cooling Law formula?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How does one integrate $$
\frac{dT}{dt} = k(T - T_0)
$$
into this?
$$
T(t) = T_0 + Ce^{kt}
$$

Comment: introduce a new variable $y=T-T_0$ then the equation simplifies to $dy/dt=ky$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dT}{dt}=k(T-t_0)\Rightarrow \frac{dT}{T-T_0}=kdt\Rightarrow \ln(T(t)-T_0)=kt + c\Rightarrow T(t) = e^{kt+c}+T_0=Ce^{kt} + T_0.$$

Comment: Damn, that was fast and accurate.  I am rusty.

Comment: @Vladimir Vargas: ¡respondiste más rápido que yo!; saludos, soy egresado de la licenciatura en matemáticas de la Universidad Antonio nariño sede Bogotá.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran saludos. Qué bueno, yo por ahora estudio física en la UN y voy en tercer semestre. No me gusta mucho Physics SE, me parece que son muy rabones.

Comment: @VladimirVargas, ¡Que bien te felicito! estas en una de las mejores universidades del país, no desaproveches esa gran oportunidad, pa' adelante con toda.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran gracias.